# Filter numpy array and restack array as multidimensional matrix

Tags: image, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to extract instances from an image mask i.e I have:
[image]

and am trying to get each instance:

[image]

for each color. Color is a different value in the images matrix, which are all integers. The individual instances should be stacked back into an array as entries in 3 Dimension, i.e (Height, Width, Instance).

I got:

```
    maxi = mask.max()
    mask = np.empty_like(mask)
    for x in range(maxi+1):
        m = np.where(mask == x, mask, -1)
        mask = np.dstack((mask,m))
    mask = mask[:,:,1:]

    return mask
```

which works but is cumbersome and slow, as well as not memory efficient.
Any suggestions?

Edited- Possible improvement:

```
    def get_instances(mask):

    instance_masks = []
    for inst_id in np.unique(mask):
        instance_mask = (mask==inst_id)
        instance_masks.append(instance_mask)
    mask = np.stack(instance_masks, axis=2)
    return mask
```

Comment: You sure about `mask = np.empty_like(mask)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over all possible values up to `mask.max()` and checking if each value is there, you could loop over only the unique values in the mask:

```
colors = np.unique(mask)
n = colors.size
color_masks = np.zeros((colors.shape[0], colors.shape[1], n))
for i, x in np.ndenumerate(colors):
    color_masks[:,:,i][mask == x] = x
return color_masks
```

Comment: Good thinking, but by design all values up to max will be present.